# LaTeX sporadically replaces dashes with $\Gamma$ when making linebreaks

Tags: line-breaking, input

I'm working on a large report and have noticed that the output pdf often contains $\Gamma$ at the end of lines, when there should be `-' instead. However this is not consistently the case, as you can see in the following screenshots:[image: A screenshot where $\Gamma$ appears]
[image: A screenshot where $\Gamma$ does not appear]

I have tried copying my entire preamble into a blank document with just Definition 3.3 from above, and then it prints correctly (without the $\Gamma$ at the linebreak). Nonetheless, I have included my preamble below, in case it is of any help:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{varwidth}

  \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
  ]{biblatex}

 \addbibresource{bib.bib}


\geometry{margin = 2.54 cm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}


\newcommand{\Hom}[2] {
    \mathrm{Hom}(#1, #2)
}
\newcommand{\id}{
    \mathrm{Id}
}

\newcommand{\tr}{
    \mathrm{Tr\,}
}

\renewcommand{\char}{
    \mathrm{char\,}
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0 pt}

\tcbset{colback=green!10!white,colframe=green!40!black}


\title{[Title]}

\author{\textbf{Author}\\ [Name]}

\date{\today}
```

Unfortunately I have not been able to reproduce this problem reliably, so I do not have a minimal working example. If you have any ideas for what I may try, that would be great!
Lastly, I have broken the report over multiple files, so perhaps the problem lies in the `\input` command?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just a guess: don't redefine `\char`.

Comment: @Sigur - thanks for the tip! I think that solves the problem. Do you know why this occurs? Also - am I supposed to mark this problem as solved somehow?

Comment: @ABanerjee \char is a tex primitive and used in many places. Don't redefine commands unless you are quite sure you understand what you are redefining.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!

Comment: @ABanerjee, good you solve the problem. Regards.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, it would be interesting to trace the errors and see why `Gamma` was used in such situation.... I mean, why not `\alpha`, for example? How redefining `\char` leads to such problem?!

Comment: By the way, you should do `\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}` and similarly where you use `\mathrm{???}\,`. Do `\DeclareMathOperator{\Char}{char}` to solve the problem of `\char`.

Comment: @Sigur Interesting but not practical... but one possible reason is that Γ is character 0 in italic font table

Comment: @Sigur Maybe you can post it as answer. Although the problem appears to be highly localized and have no MWE at the moment, MWE could be added and it may not be *that* localized (on the other hand there are like 500 commands that can be "accidentally redefined" and break everything so it may not worth it...)

Comment: The fact you had to say `\renewcommand\char` rather than `\newcommand\char` is the red flag that warns you of such a potential conflict.

Comment: Update, Indeed I can't reproduce the problem either... it's highly localized.

Comment: @Sigur I would speculate that the reason Gamma and not alpha shows up has something to do with the fact that Gamma is located in slot 0 of the (roman) font table.  i.e., `\char 0`

Comment: Another telltale is that the first appearance of a command such as `$\mathcal{K}$` raises an error about `\mathrm` being only usable in math mode. Never disregard errors particularly when they're weird!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, I'd say *yellow flag* as a Formula 1 enthusiastic. lol

Comment: By the way I'd also recommend my "regex substitute rest of file" package so you can e.g. replace all occurrence of `\char` with `\mychar` to avoid conflict. Not necessarily a good idea though

Comment: @egreg - Will do, thank you very much! I feel a lot of LaTeX is using the (wrong) ad hoc solution you've come up with until someone shows you the right way to do it, so thank you for that!

Comment: @ABanerjee With your definition, you wouldn't get a thin space in front of the operator (that's sometimes required) and you'd get a thin space after it also when you do `\Tr(A+B)`, where it's not wanted.